# Qt - QStringList to QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qbytearray

What is the most efficient way of converting `QStringList` to `QByteArray`?

I have found many examples of similar conversions but never the one I needed or were just needlessly too complicated.

---

The code sanitize a string input and then convert it to `QByteArray`. I am struggling with the latter part.

```
void MainWindow::on_suicideButton_clicked()
{
    QString input = ui->lineEdit->text();
    try{
        if(ui->lineEdit->text().contains("0x")||ui->lineEdit->text().contains(",")||ui->lineEdit->text().contains("-"))
        {
            input = input.replace("0x","");
            if (input.contains(',')) input = input.replace(",", "");
            // QString trim = input.trimmed();
            // input = trim;//.split(',', ' ', '-');
            QStringList inputArray = input.split('-');
            QByteArray output = inputArray;
        }
        //printf("%s\n", input);

        ui->lineEdit->setText(input);
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc &) {input = " ";}
}
```

`QStringList inputArray = input.split('-');`  is important (or at least I believe it to be so), as I would need to split the bytes into separate chunks in order to perform various operations on them.

---

Here is an example, in order for you to see what kind of operations I would like to do:

```
char MainWindow::checkSum(QByteArray &b)
{
    char val = 0x00;
    char i;
    foreach (i, b)
    {
       val ^= i;
    }

    return val;
}
```

Comment: What is a QArrayList? Do you mean QStringList?

Comment: I can't find any info about `QArrayList` in QT docs.

Comment: Bless you, just realised what I had written. :)

Comment: Wrote it wrongly by mistake, I appologise.

Comment: if you just want to sanitize the user input, why do you use a stringlist? As I understand the whole lineedit.text should go into a Bytearray. Should the dashes "-" stay, or should they be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply apply `QByteArray::append(const QString &str)` for each string in your list. [Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#append-5) says it will automatically convert string:

> Appends the string str to this byte array. The Unicode data is
>   converted into 8-bit characters using QString::toUtf8().

So you can write something like this:

```
QByteArray output;

// inputArray - your QStringList
foreach (const QString &str, inputArray)
{
    output.append(str);
}
```

But if you don't want default conversation you can append strings converted to `const char *` as stated in the same docs:

> You can disable this function by defining QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII when you
>   compile your applications. You then need to call QString::toUtf8() (or
>   QString::toLatin1() or QString::toLocal8Bit()) explicitly if you want
>   to convert the data to const char *.

And do something like this:

```
output.append(str.toUtf8()); // or str.toLatin1() or str.toLocal8Bit()
```

**Edit 1**

Just found that you can also use `+=` instead of `append()` :

```
output += str;
```

This would behave the same way as `append()` as said [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#operator-2b-eq-3).

Comment: Just returned to the problem and I think your solution is the closest to what I believe it could be a solution to my problem. However,  using that loop only appends chars to the byte array, ergo the array is built up with elements containing single char per byte. If I need to pass a hex string (for example, 'A1-B2-C3-D4-E5') I would need to keep the clusters whole (meaning one byte would be A1, the following B2, et cetera).

Comment: @JoeCarr , Yes if you'll convert "A1" it would convert separately each char. To keep it together one solution is to convert as it is and then reconvert keeping in mind you need to extract 2 chars each time. Another solution is to represent 2 chars e.g. "A1" as one char for example it equals 161 in decimal so you can represent it as ASCII symbol (use 'unsigned char') and then convert it. This way you'll have the exact representation of "A1" but it would be a bit more difficult to reconvert back depending on what you need.

Answer (score 5):

How about a QDataStream to serialize the string list?

```
// Fill the data buffer
QByteArray data;
QStringList list{"foo", "bar", "foobar"};
QDataStream dataStreamWrite(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
dataStreamWrite << list;

// Do whatever you want with the raw data

// And if you want to convert it back to a QStringList
QDataStream dataStreamRead(data);
QStringList list2;
dataStreamRead >> list2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you will have to `join` the strings with a `separator` of your choice, then have to use one  of the `QString` functions to convert to `QByteArray` depending on the `QStrings` encoding

```
QStringList strlist; //Let's assume there's a value in there

QChar separator = ''; //Any QChar or QString you want to use to separate the QStringList
strlist.join(separator).toLocal8Bit(); //8 bit
strlist.join(separator).toUtf8(); //UTF-8
strlist.join(separator).toLatin1(); //Latin
```

**Edit 1 to fit your code**

```
if(input.contains("0x")||input.contains(",")||input.contains("-"))
{
    //Just replace the chars you don't cant, then convert back to QByteArray
    input = input.replace("0x","");
    input = input.replace(",", "");
    input = input.replace("-", "");
    QByteArray output = input.toLocal8Bit();
}
```

**Edit 2 with QStringList**

```
if(input.contains("0x")||input.contains(",")||input.contains("-"))
{
    //Just replace the chars you don't cant, then convert back to QByteArray
    input = input.replace("0x","");
    input = input.replace(",", "");
    QStringList inputArray = input.Split('-');

    //Do what you want with your list
    //...

    //Converts it back
    QByteArray output = inputArray.join('').toLocal8Bit();
}
```

I cannot test the code right now, so there might be a typo

Comment: @joe-carr Updated, there was no need to split then join back when a simple `replace` could tdo the trick

Comment: Yeah it looks much cleaner now, however, the functionality of the larger function is to take the input(which is a string) and convert it to a hex in order to have other functions to be performed on it (checksum for example). Having an input (eg 'A1-B2-C3-D4-E5', or'0xA1-0xB2-0xC3-0xD4-0xE5') and have it populated in a QByteArray would make it much easier to have the input data manipulated.

Comment: @JoeCarr My 1st edit already gives you a QByteArray. I'm not sure you even know what you want. Do you want to manipulate a QByteArray, or a QStringList ? If you only want to manipulate the QByteArray, you don't need a QStringList

Comment: Having the inputArray.join('').toLocal8Bit(); gives me an ambiguous call to overload the function error.

Comment: @JoeCarr Please post the error so I can help you more. Which part causes it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133627/discussion-between-florent-uguet-and-joe-carr).

Answer (score 2):

As dydil also answered, you can use [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html).

For example:

```
QByteArray serialize(QStringList data)
{
    QByteArray byteArray;
    QDataStream out(&byteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << data;
    return byteArray;
}

void deserialize(QByteArray byteArray, QStringList *data)
{
    QDataStream in(&byteArray, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    in >> *data;
}
```